# 500 (Internal Server Error) - jstree rendering node display spins

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, jstree

I have an asp.net solution with default home page that includes an alphabatized index / tree view of schools.  Within that index are the parent schools, and then their children.

Example:

A
 -Apple School District
      -Apple Middle School

Recently when I added a new school I get a spinning wheel on that homepage as it tries to load the tree list.

If I open Chrome Debugger, I can see:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
https://test.site.net/Administration/Organizations.aspx/GetOrganizationTreeData
```

**GetOrganizationTreeData**  Is a function that runs a query that loads my list of parent organizations and child organizations.  I have stepped through this c# code in VS with no errors.

Then it looks like it takes that data and renders it to a javascript organizations.js which leverages jstree.js

I'm new to debugging, but this is what I've done or noticed so far:
It's behaving like I've reached a max amount of nodes i can pull back for my tree.

If have 722 organizations.  It works like a champ.
The minute I add #723, i get a spinning wheel and the error above.

***It doesnt matter if I delete #723 that was recently added, or if I pick one from the middle and delete say org #55.  As long as I don't go over 722 total orgs it loads.***

This and the fact that my VS C# debugger runs the query succefully and I can't trigger any errors in C#, makes me think that the issue is with the java scripts that are rendering the returned query.

I'm trying to step through the google chrome debugger and java script.  I have Event Listeners Load, Error and PopState selected.

Do you have any advice or tips and tricks that might point me to the error faster?

How would you let debug run for java, but see the last thing it was executing before the spinning wheel?

update:  Network in debug dev tools in chrome just shows the following for: **GetOrganizationTreeData**

```
{Message: "There was an error processing the request.", StackTrace: "", ExceptionType: ""}
ExceptionType: ""
Message: "There was an error processing the request."
StackTrace: ""
```

Comment: If the response from the server is `500 Internal Server Error` then it's not an issue with the client-side script processing the response, it's an issue in the server (C#) code. The spinner is likely sat spinning because your code starts the spinner when it triggers the request to the server but only stops the spinner when it gets valid data back. Have a look at the 'Network' tab in Chrome Dev Tools - clicking on the for the request to GetOrganizationTreeData and looking at the Response might show why it's failing =)

Comment: Okay, thx.  That's the conclusion I keep coming to (that it's server side), though it's confusing because it doesn't seem to be related to a specific row (org data).  I havent tried the network tab, ill give that shot.

Should I be getting a error in my C# code; stepping through seems successful?

Comment: @Rob Actually just for clarity.  Can i dismiss any .js files within my project as root cause if the browser error is 500?

Comment: If the error you're seeing is `500 Internal Server Error` then it's a problem server-side. It might also be worth looking in the 'Application' part of the Windows Event Log, that might give you details regarding what's blowing up on you :)

Comment: @Rob Thx, I updated the thread with the network response in dev tools....

Just shows a stacktrace, but not sure how to get more info about it.  I'll go look at the windows event log.

Comment: no errors in the windows event log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that if I reproduced the error on my local server I could get more errors in the browser debugging window; specificically the network section showed a JSON max length error.  Resolution is readily available on google for JSON max length